# How is this power set generating function working

Tags: haskell

While trying to generate power set for a given list, I came across this function over the internet. There was no explanation, but testing suggests that it seems to work correctly. I am not able to understand how this function is working. I will be thankful for any such explanations.

```
generateSubset [] = [[]]
generateSubset (x:xs) = let p = generateSubset xs in p ++ map (x:) p
```

Comment: My favorite way to build a power set: `powerSet = filterM (const [False,True])` (requires `import Control.Monad (filterM)`)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: `powerSet = subsequences`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a property of powersets that's easy to prove: P(A ∪ B) = {a ∪ b | a ∈ P(A), b ∈ P(B)}. In particular, if we decompose a particular set S into an element s and all the elements S' that are not s, then

```
P(S) = P({s} ∪ S')
     = {a ∪ b | a ∈ P({s}), b ∈ P(S')}.
```

Now, P({s}) is small enough that we can compute it by hand: P({s}) = {{}, {s}}. Using this fact, we learn

```
P(S) = {a ∪ b | a ∈ {{}, {s}}, b ∈ P(S')}
     = {b | b ∈ P(S')} ∪ {{s} ∪ b | b ∈ P(S')}
     = P(S') ∪ {{s} ∪ b | b ∈ P(S')}
     = let p = P(S') in p ∪ {{s} ∪ b | b ∈ p}
```

That is, one way to compute the powerset of a non-empty set is to choose an element, compute the powerset for the remainder, then either add or don't add the element to each of the subsets. The function you showed simply turns this into code, using lists as a representation of sets:

```
-- P         ({s} ∪ S') = let p = P(S')             in p  ∪ {{s} ∪ b | b ∈ p}
generateSubset (x:xs)   = let p = generateSubset xs in p ++     map (x:) p
```

The only thing left is to give a base case for the recursion, and that just comes straight from the definition of a powerset:

```
-- P          ({}) = {{}}
generateSubset []  = [[]]
```

Comment: What that property means is that every subset of `A ∪ B` is the union of a subset of `A` and a subset of `B`.  Thus, to compute the powerset of `S`, we can decompose `S` into subsets `A` and `B`, compute their powersets `P(A)` and `P(B)`, and combine them by taking unions.

Comment: @Heatsink Seems like divide and conquer!

Answer (score 4):

The code you gave uses a lot of Haskell's syntactic sugar.  (As others have already covered the semantics, I'll omit that.)  Here's the main syntax I noticed in the code:

- lack of type annotations.  Haskell uses type inference, which makes type annotations optional (but recommended).  Use GHCi to determine the type:

  ```
  *Main> :t generateSubset
  generateSubset :: [a] -> [[a]]
  ```
- pattern matching.  See [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) for a nice introduction.
- let expressions.  Again, see [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be).
- partial application -- `(x:)`.  [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) for the win!
- operator sections -- `(x:)` again.  This allows for partial application of an infix function (in this case, `:`).  It's the same as:

  ```
  myCons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
  myCons e es = e : es

  myPartial :: [a] -> [a]
  myPartial = myCons x -- partial application
  ```
- use of function/operator precedences -- `p ++ map (x:) p`.  This is parsed as `(p) ++ (map (x:) p)`, because [function application always has higher precedence than infix operator application](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

The power set of the empty list is a list containing only the empty list.

To calculate the power set of a non-empty list it first calculates the power set of the tail. It then concatenates that power set with a version of the power set where the head has been prepended to all the subsets. So if the power set of the tail is `[[2,3],[2],[3],[]]` and the head is `1`, the resulting power set will be `[[], [3], [2], [2,3], [1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`.

Comment: What is the meaning of syntax: `generateSubset (x:xs)` Why not simply `generateSubset x` as the function is only accepting a list?

Comment: `(x:xs)` makes `x` the head and `xs` the tail of the list. This is called pattern matching. Read more about that at http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching

Comment: @tauli So, through a concatenation of head and tail, effectively, we are giving the full list. Right?

Comment: Right. A list like `[1,2,3]` can also be written as `1:2:3:[]` or `1:[2,3]`. The last example matches the pattern `(x:xs)`, thus `x`becomes `1` and `xs` becomes `[2,3]`.